# get the last element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following elements:

```
fieldset (class="A") > div > p > several input and labels
```

I want to get the last div in the fieldset - with the div tag included

i.e. not from the "p" tag that is inside the last "div"

I tried :

```
$('.A').children().last().html()
```

but it gives me the last div without the div tag (i.e. from the p inside)

any ideas why or how i can include the div tag in the query?

html:

```
<div class="form">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <fieldset class="A">
        {% for b in B%}
            <div id="b-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                {{b.as_p}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}    
     </fieldset>
  </div>
```

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: Do you really need to chain method calls when a simple selector will do: `$('.A > div:last-child')`?

Answer (score 6):

[**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will only get the `innerHTML`. You can make use of the native `outerHTML` property by retrieving the native DOM element

```
$('.A').children().last()[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: @A.Wolff, doesnt he want `<div id="b-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">` or *I want to get the last div in the fieldset - with the div tag included* ?

Comment: @A.Wolff, me neither which means I was lucky ;-)

Comment: Does @brad want a string? outerHTML returns only a string, not div element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can clone the last div. Add it to some temp jquery element and take `.html()` will give you outer html of last `div`

```js
$(function(){
  var tempDiv = $('<div></div>');
  tempDiv.append($('.A').children().last().clone());
  alert(tempDiv.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <fieldset class="A">
            <div id="a">
               <p>a</p>
            </div>
            <div id="b">
               <p>b</p>
            </div> 
            <div id="c">
               <p>c</p>
            </div> 
     </fieldset>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use other functions. You can just try

```
$(".A > div:last-child")
```

to select your last div with DIV tag included.

Comment: I believe this is the one that should be marked as correct.